# Marquee style progressbar freezes when adding row into datagrid in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, progress-bar

I am using a BackgroundWorker to do some work and show its progress on screen using a marquee style progressbar. I update the progressbar in the ProgressChanged event, along side adding a row in a datagridview. The datagridview has AllowUserToAddRows=false. Apparently this combinations seems to be freezing the marquee style progressbar. If I use a style=blocks progressbar, it all works fine. I am using .NET 4.5 on Windows 7 with Aero theme.
My question is

1. Is it a bug?
2. Is there a workaround, within my constraints

Below is a sample code that demonstrates the problem. Add a BackgroundWorker, 2 ProgressBars and one button onto a windows form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressBar2.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
        progressBar1.Visible = true;
        progressBar2.Visible = true;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\BackedupFolder\Photos");
        FileInfo[] files1 = di.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        int tot = files1.Length, i = 0;
        foreach (var q in files1) {
            CheckSum(q);
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(++i * 100 / tot);
        }
    }

    byte[] CheckSum(FileInfo f) {
        MD5 hashAlgo = MD5.Create();
        return hashAlgo.ComputeHash(f.OpenRead());
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
        progressBar2.Update();
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage > 100 ? 100 : e.ProgressPercentage;
        dataGridView1.RowCount++;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
        progressBar2.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

1. Just to be clear, I need to show progress for a long task (I/O and CPU intensive) using a progressbar while adding new data into the datagridview
2. If you replace the actual task with say Thread.Sleep, the marquee works fine

EDIT:

I will keep this question open so hopefully someone knows why this happens. It is really intriguing that the DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows affects the marquee styled (includes the marquee animation in style=continuous) ProgressBar

In the meanwhile, the only reasonable workaround I could find was to move my ProgressBar onto a a new form, and instead of showing the progressbar docked at the bottom of my current form, I show a ProgressDialog with the bar and a cancel button.

EDIT:

1. My real application does far more complex and time consuming processing (imagine a LINQ join comparing files and checksums) than the sample shown here. The sample is more of my best effort to isolate the issue from real code.
2. The line progressBar2.Update() is really not needed, I just put it there to express that I have tried that too.
3. In my real code, I use a single progressbar with style=continuous, which is a hybrid between style=blocks and style=marquee. And while using that I noticed the marquee was not updating but the block progress was, which is when I did all sorts of experiments to zero on to the actual issue.
4. Also, in the real code, other than some processing the only GUI update I have to do is add a row into the grid.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem on Windows 8.  Marquee works.

Comment: You are calling ReportProgress at a high rate, particularly the second and subsequent times you run your program.  Which are fast because all the file data got cached in the file system cache.  When you call it *too* fast then you can flood the UI thread with invoke requests and it doesn't get around to its low priority tasks.  Like keeping that marquee going.  Never invoke more then 20 times per second, plenty fast enough for a human eye.

Comment: @HansPassant: Please check my last edit. Also, ProgressChanged is just an event on UI thread. And the only UI activity I am doing is adding a new row into my grid (which is most cases would not even be rendered on screen). So why would that impact my marquee? Also, I have seen the same behavior when the events are few and far between (due to say calculation of CheckSum on large files)